# Base64 decode a section of a string using re and base64 modules

Tags: python, regex, base64, decode

Can anyone demonstrate how you can base64 decode a particular section of a string using a regex search?  I would like the final result to return the entire string but with the base64 areas decoded.

**Text between the category tags and subcategory tags should be decoded and then entire strinf should be returned.**

```
<attack_headline><site_id>1</site_id><category>U1FMIEluamVjdGlvbg==</category><subcategory>Q2xhc3NpYyBTUUwgQ29tbWVudCAmcXVvdDstLSZxdW90Ow==</subcategory><client_ip>192.168.1.102</client_ip><date>1363807248</date><gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff><reference_id>E711-3EFB-5F43-5FAC</reference_id></attack_headline>
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: you shouldn't apply a regular expression to XML or HTML. That's just asking for trouble. Parse the XML and HTML, decode the relevant tag attribute/text, then print out XML/HTML again.

Comment: Matt for this particular objective ... nothing. I was merely looking for a 1 - 2 liner where someone stores the string in a variable (which is what I would be dealing with anyway) and then simply use a regex() and possibly the base64.b64decode() to correct the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, here's an example using `lxml.etree`, which assumes your input is XML (if HTML, use `lxml.html` instead):

```
>>> import base64
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> text = "<attack_headline><site_id>1</site_id><category>U1FMIEluamVjdGlvbg==</category><subcategory>Q2xhc3NpYyBTUUwgQ29tbWVudCAmcXVvdDstLSZxdW90Ow==</subcategory><client_ip>192.168.1.102</client_ip><date>1363807248</date><gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff><reference_id>E711-3EFB-5F43-5FAC</reference_id></attack_headline>"
>>> xml = lxml.etree.fromstring(text)
>>> for tag_with_base64 in ('category','subcategory'):
...     node = xml.find(tag_with_base64)
...     if node:
...         node.text = base64.b64decode(node.text)
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(xml)
'<attack_headline><site_id>1</site_id><category>SQL Injection</category><subcategory>Classic SQL Comment &amp;quot;--&amp;quot;</subcategory><client_ip>192.168.1.102</client_ip><date>1363807248</date><gmt_diff>0</gmt_diff><reference_id>E711-3EFB-5F43-5FAC</reference_id></attack_headline>'
```

Comment: isdev... You rock ... Thanks dude.

Comment: Question, Can xml.find() accept more than one value. Since i need to search for two different tags

Comment: I want to decode anything string that is base64 encoded in the line and then return the full line. You did this in  your example except you missed the string inside <category>

Comment: I am getting node.text = base64.b64decode(node.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: maybe not all clauses have both 'category' and 'subcategory' tags, will update answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
events = client.service.get_recent_attacks("",epoch_time_last,epoch_time_now,1,"",15)
text = re.sub('(?<!<\/attack_headline>)\s*\n\s*', '',  events)
xml = lxml.etree.fromstring(text)
for tag_with_base64 in ('category','subcategory'):
    node = xml.find(tag_with_base64)
    node.text = base64.b64decode(node.text)
lxml.etree.tostring(xml)
```

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "dDAPI-NTLM_demo.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "dDAPI-NTLM_demo.py", line 12, in main
    cl.get_recent_attacks(client)
  File "/root/helpers.py", line 66, in get_recent_attacks
    node.text = base64.b64decode(node.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'